# Help embedding categories into Switchee value field

Tags: categories, embeds, switchee

I’m trying to embed categories into a Switchee value field but can’t get it to work. Can you help?

To try to deal with the parsing order problem, I call the Switchee embed from my site/index template:

```
{embed="site/.cases" categories="{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" style="linear" backspace=“1”}{category_url_title}|{/exp:channel:categories}"}
```

And this is the site/.cases template:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_1}" parse="inward"}

    {case value="{embed:categories}"}
        {embed="site/page" channel="page"}
    {/case}

    {case default="yes"}
        {embed="site/404"}
    {/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

It fails.

I tried embedding via Low Variables and Template Morsels both directly and through a similar embed method as above and they failed, too.

I’m at my wits end! Any tips?

Comment: If you output the value of {embed:categories} outside of switchee, does the formatting match segment_1?

Comment: Yes, my output is: category_1|category_2|category_3 which would make a match of the following URL: http://example.com/category_1

Comment: So you're getting the default, even when you expect a seg1 match? Might also check what the template debug for switchee says using debug="yes" parameter.

Comment: That's right, Romans: 

   Switchee: evaluating variable about
(0.049297 / 6.95MB)      Switchee: default case found for variable 'about'. This will be returned if no match is found.

Comment: To clarify, if I create embed a Low Variable into the case value like this:

`{case value="{lv-categories}"}
        {embed="site/page" channel="page"}
    {/case}`

And then define the Low Variable as my categories...

`about|sample-category|support|visit`

...it works. But if, in my Low Variable I replace it with what will generate the same thing...

`{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" style="linear" backspace="1"}{category_url_title}|{/exp:channel:categories}`

...it fails.

Comment: I could be wrong (nah...), but this might be a bug. I'm trying different combos and finding similar results with the latest switchee. You also might post this on devotee if the developer doesn't catch it here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/switchee/viewforum/466